# PHP:give json data to only phonegap apps?

Tags: php, json, cordova

so i have a domain www.example.com and i have an app that access some dir in the domain to get json data for example www.example.com/phonegapdata/index.php

anyone can get the data if they want by typing the url or via getjson i am using the following code

```
$.getJSON(url,{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);  
    }); //getJS
```

How can i make it secure so that only my app, can access it.?
Is there a way to make it more secure.?

Comment: Please share with us in detail if the url is user specific. Because, I find the need to "secure" the url only if it is specific to a user and the user is logged in.

Comment: no the url is not user specific..what i want is that ppl with my app can only access it and not by other mean i.e, browsers etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to "secure" any web endpoint is:

1) restrict access to files, directories, and/or service endpoints.

This, in turn, means that you must:

2) provide some means of authentication.  The server needs to know "who" is requesting access in order to permit or deny that access.

SUGGESTIONS:

- Familiarize yourself with ["HTTP Basic Authentication"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- Configure your web site to authenticate.  Verify that you can access the items you want with a username and password in your browser.  Verify that you *cannot* access the items you want to restrict without the right credentials.
- If you don't want users to enter a username and password themselves, then simply program your phonegap app to send username and password in the HTTP headers when it connects to your server.  For example:

[PhoneGap FileTransfer with HTTP basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322194/phonegap-filetransfer-with-http-basic-authentication)

```
authHeaderValue = function(username, password) {
    var tok = username + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    return "Basic " + hash;
};

options.headers = {'Authorization': authHeaderValue('Bob', '1234') };
```

Once you get this working, you can substitute something more sophisticated.  But this should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: the username and password in this case will need to be hard coded in the app. so any one might open the code and see it..is there a more dynamic way..i have asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919071/phonegap-authentication-without-username-password