# Phonegap Authentication without username/password

Tags: php, android, cordova, authentication

i have a phonegap app and i want only **my app users** to access the api from where i am getting the data.

I am using php as my back end.

What i did was i created a key and was authenticating the key on the server. But the key is hard-coded in the app meaning someone can look at the code and figure out the key and pass it as a parameter and gain access to my api which i don't want.

Furthermore the key also be seen by using a proxy.

is there a way to dynamically generate the key on both the app and the server so it gets authenticated? Or some other way.

**i don't** want the user to give any kind of username/password.

**i don't** want the user to register or login..the user has no role in the authentication..i am authenticating the **app**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure this can be done,

But several things before you should start.

- Create a new **table** to store all the **api keys** which we are
  going to **generate per user** when they are **registering through
  the app**.

PHP Side:

- Grab users password or any unique thing Eg: **UDID** Andriod, in IOS
  they have restricted access to UDID and you might have to store some
  unique generated id in the **keychain**.
- Then When we have the **password** and **UDID** you can put them
  together (or anyway you want) and encrypt with [Sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) (or any
  encryption algorithm) And save it to the **api key table**
- Every time when a **request hit on the api** you can grab the **api key**
  from the **header and validate** it with the **database** and see.

App Side:

- When the user **login through the app** if it is **successful**,
  **pass the api key to the user** and **save it inside the app** for **further use**.
- Also when your going to **request the data from the api** you can
  **retrieve** the **api key stored inside the app**, Then put it as a **header in the request** and send.

Few Extra things:

- Also you can create a **private key** on both sides (Server and App)
  then store it in the **api key table** and **encrypt the request**
  which is the **server and app only knows** using the **private keys**
  stored on both sides.
- Also you can go for advance authentications like **[oAuth](http://oauth.net/about/)**

Comment: i don't want the user to register or login..the user has no role in the authentication..will this still work then?

Comment: @krv Why don't you want to register and login??..i don't **recommend you this..And my answer will not work for you..Also your **api** will be vulnerable..You can't restrict access **without authentication**..You have to use hard code which anyone will be able to see.

Comment: @krv then also it won't be an **api**

Comment: the app can be for kids or people from rural areas so i dont want that..in a way i am not authenticating the user but i am authenticating the app..so the server logic is "is the request from my app" if yes send the data if no then don't

Comment: @krv i have an idea..You can use end to end vpn to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use RSA, the popular Algorithm in SSL/TLS. The point is a private key and public key pair.

Here's the library and example for PHP:

[Encrypt and Decrypt text with RSA in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484246/encrypt-and-decrypt-text-with-rsa-in-php)

And here's the library for Javascript:

[RSA Encryption Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685645/rsa-encryption-javascript)

And my personal suggestion: to negotiate a random key store in ram for later usage rather than use the key pair for all message exchange. Because it's a high workload for server(15times more than client). And you can define a object to store the session key in private member.

```
funciton keyStoreObject() {
    this.publicKey = ''; //this is public
    var sessionKey = ''; //this is private
    this.negotiate() = function () { sessionKey = 123456; //You can access private sessionKey }
    this.decypt = function (str) {...}; //And write your code here
}
```

and so create a instance:

```
var keyStore = new KeyStoreObject;
//so now you can
keyStore.negotiate();
```

About private member, read more here:
http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Also, you need to implement a session key store on server side and including a expire time. For small instance, `serialize()` or SQLite can be used.

Actually, the sessionKey is not fully secure(in theoretically). A desktop browser can make DDoS attack. Human validation like captcha code can help you.